# Turn off email notification from abrt (Automatic Bug Reporting Tool)

Tags: linux, centos, centos6.2

I'm configuring CentOS 6.2 and have seen a few "[abrt] full crash report" emails.  I understand that abrt is useful for creating crash dumps and what not, so I don't want to disable the service, I just would like to stop getting the crash report emails.

I probably have to add something to the config file in /etc/abrt/abrt.conf.  I can't seem to find anything in my searches.  Any idea?  Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is my abrt.conf, which is rather simple.

```
[root@myhost~]# cat /etc/abrt/abrt.conf
# Enable this if you want abrtd to auto-unpack crashdump tarballs which appear
# in this directory (for example, uploaded via ftp, scp etc).
# Note: you must ensure that whatever directory you specify here exists
# and is writable for abrtd. abrtd will not create it automatically.
#
#WatchCrashdumpArchiveDir = /var/spool/abrt-upload

# Max size for crash storage [MiB] or 0 for unlimited
#
MaxCrashReportsSize = 1000

# Specify where you want to store coredumps and all files which are needed for
# reporting. (default:/var/spool/abrt)
#
#DumpLocation = /var/spool/abrt
```

And a listing of /etc/abrt:

```
[root@myhost~]# ls -la /etc/abrt
total 32
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root  4096 Apr 13 06:14 .
drwxr-xr-x. 97 root root 12288 Apr 13 03:50 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   527 Dec 13 22:50 abrt-action-save-package-data.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   572 Dec 13 22:50 abrt.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   175 Dec 13 22:50 gpg_keys
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Apr 13 06:13 plugins

[root@myhost~]# ls -la /etc/abrt/plugins/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr 13 06:13 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Apr 13 06:14 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  278 Dec 13 22:50 CCpp.conf
```

Actually all of those conf files above are only a few lines and do not mention anything about mail, email, or notifications.

**UPDATE**

Since I have disabled `abrtd`, I've been seeing these in /var/log/messages:

```
myhost abrt: abrt daemon is not running. If it crashed, /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern contains a stale value, consider resetting it to 'core'
```

The [proper](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=752014) way to stop the `abrt` service is:

```
service abrt-ccpp stop
chkconfig abrt-ccpp off
```

Comment: I assume you are getting emails/notifications locally on the host at the command line, and not in an actual external mailbox?

Comment: The emails are sent from the "user" user to the "root" user.  Postfix is configured to hand off any mail to our mail relay server, and anything going to root forwards to my email address (per /etc/aliases).  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem running RHEL 6.2.  It seems that Mailx wasn't a separate module in the version of abrt being used.  I found the best way is to either blacklist programs by adding it to */etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf*:

```
BlackList = program1, program2, program3
```

(followed by `service abrtd restart`)

Or by disabling abrt all together:

`# chkconfig abrtd off`

(followed by `service abrtd stop`)

Comment: I disabled abrt completely.  I'll keep the Blacklist conf in mind though, thanks.

Comment: The last two lines mean `sudo chkconfig abrtd off` and `sudo service abrtd stop;`

Answer (score 5):

You're likely receiving these because the mailx plugin for abrtd has been installed. There are a number of different ways it could be invoked, so what you need to do is look in your `/etc/abrt/abrtd.conf` file for instances of the string "Mailx" and remove those lines. For example, you may see:

```
ActionsAndReporters = Mailx("[abrt] a crash occurs")
```

which tells abrtd to email out a report on every crash, or you could see

```
CCpp:httpd = Mailx("[abrt] Apache crash")
```

which causes abrtd to email out an alert whenever the process httpd crashes.

So look through your config file for any such instances of Mailx being invoked, remove then, restart abrtd, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I added some more info to my question, but unfortunately I do not see anything about mail in the conf files.

Comment: @Banjer the right place to look is **/etc/libreport/events.d/abrt_event.conf**. I found that place by invoking `rpm -qc abrt`.

Comment: such a awkward configuration method for such a helpful daemon.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me is to leave abrtd daemon running while setting `/etc/libreport/plugins/mailx.conf` in order to put there some fake values for example

```
Subject=nomail
EmailFrom=nomailFrom@xxx.it
EmailTo=nomailTo@xxx.it
```

then restart abrtd service to take affect of new configuration.